How do non-blocking algorithms vs user mode synchronization relate to each other?
How do non-blocking algorithms¹ vs user mode synchronization² relate to each other?
Usually these concepts are spoken about separately. And problem is that I don't understand it clearly, because I am not experienced in this area.
If we talk about Venn diagram, then I now have this understanding of ​​synchronization approaches in .NET:

Is my understanding shown on image right?
Can you provide more interesting examples for each 'user mode' and
'lock free' areas?
¹ By non-blocking I mean Interlocked.Exchange or SpinLock.
² By user mode synchronization I mean lock or AutoResetEvent.

Could you explain/define the term "non-blocking algorithm"? Also when you talk about "user mode synchronization", what other modes of synchronization exist?

"non-blocking algorithm" for synchronization I mean 'Interlocked.Exchange' or 'SpinLock'. See definition here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm .  Maybe I understand it wrong, but as I understand all user mode locking use non blocking algorithms. And it is possible that not all non blocking algorithms are implemented in .net.  Other modes - Kernel mode (e.g. AutoResetEvent).

So if I understand correctly by "non-blocking" you mean lock-free, and by "user mode synchronization" you mean using the lock statement, correct?

"non-blocking" you mean lock-free - yes

"user mode synchronization" you mean using the lock statement - not only lock (but including lock)

maybe consult the chapter 29 Primitive Thread Synchronization Constructs  in CLR via C# (4th edition). Richter makes this distinction (user vs kernel) and provides lots of examples and illustrations.

I don't get the essence of the question - difference is simple, user-mode locks are blocking and fast (cause of they don't rely on kernel structures). Lock-free locks, by definition, don't block threads.

As a summary for .NET - including all of that at the same time - Interlocked class, volatile keyword, Volatile.Read(), Volatile.Write(), Spin-based locks to some extent - doesn't lead to blocking behavior.

Volatile story is rather about instructions reordering optimization prohibit and atomicity, than locking. And like Interlocked class - it doesn't ensure that consumer gets the latest value. Getting latest value - It's all about fight against cache coherence protocol in modern multicore CPUs, imho.

I would recommend you to find the details to your question in "The Art of Multiprocessor Programming" - awesome read. Awesome tasks after each chapter too. This is fundamental book.

A spinlock is not a non-blocking algorithm.  It has "lock" in the name.  Waiting threads spin forever if the thread holding the lock gets stuck or dies, thus doesn't meet the definition of even the weakest form of non-blocking (see the wikipedia article you linked).  The fact that you can write your own spinlock using lock-free-atomic building blocks doesn't make the whole algorithm lock-free.  (A more interesting example that's normally lock-free, but blocks in corner cases: Lock-free Progress Guarantees in a circular buffer queue)

That's why i added for spinlocks - up to some extent.
